# TypeORM with Oracle: How to remove double quotes in the DDL commands?

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

The TypeORM creates tables and columns using double quotes in its name.
Example: create table "users" ("id" number, "name" varchar2(30)"... etc

The problem is, if I trying to query the table (using any Oracle SQL client), I have to use double quotes.
I can't query like this: select * from users. I have to use: select * from "users".

First try: I created my migrations by hand using the command queryRunner.query("create table users..."). It worked, but when I try to use the user repository, TypeORM says the table is not found, because it tries to insert using "user" as the table name. Like this: insert into "user" ("id", "name", ....

For Oracle:
select * from "user" is different than select * from user.
If the table was created with double quotes, it will be find only with double quotes.

I'm using typeorm version "^0.3.12".

I know in old versions of typeorm there was a parameter called quoteIdentifiers = false, that would solve this. But it doesn't work in the new version.

Any solution for that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out a way to do it in TypeORM and need a last resort workaround, you can create an INSTEAD OF CREATE trigger to intercept the create DDL and remove the double-quotes. But you really want to solve it instead on your client-side. If you do need to try this workaround, this is how you'd do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t INSTEAD OF CREATE ON SCHEMA
  DECLARE
    var_sql_count pls_integer;
    var_original_sql varchar2(32767);
    var_new_sql varchar2(32767);
    tab_sql ora_name_list_t := ora_name_list_t();
  BEGIN
    var_sql_count := original_sql_txt(tab_sql);
    
    IF var_sql_count > 0
    THEN
      BEGIN
        /*
        ** Assemble the SQL pieces together
        */
        FOR i IN 1..var_sql_count
        LOOP
          var_original_sql := var_original_sql||tab_sql(i);
        END LOOP;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          NULL;
      END;
    END IF;
    
    /*
    ** Make changes to the DDL
    */
    IF ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE'
    THEN
      var_new_sql := REPLACE(var_original_sql,'"');
    ELSE
      var_new_sql := var_old_sql;
    END IF;
    
    /*
    ** Execute new DDL in place of old
    */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_new_sql;
  END;
```

Test:

```
create table test2 ("col1" integer);

SELECT column_name
  FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'TEST2'
```

Result: `COL1`  (upper case)

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. But TypeORM will keep looking for tables with double quotes. It will try to insert, delete, select, etc with double quotes and will not find these tables/columns. the final solution will be something on TypeORM. Thanks again.